# How to get user input text value and call that value when i need them in another form

Tags: php, html

In my first form, i have the two dates value and i want them back on in the third form. Please can anyone help me?  I already tried with in put type hidden but when the page is reloaded, there is no value in the hidden box. Please tell me the othet good way.

Comment: use session storage to store value on first form submit and get value whenever required

Comment: use session/local storage

Answer (score -1):

If the date value in the first form is saving in Database  them you can persist it easily.

If the date value in the first form is not saving in Database, then you can do it with use JS/JQuery.
Steps -

1. Get the content of the Date field.
2. Set that value in the third form.
3. Also save it in cookie.
4. Use that cookie to persist the field value when page loads if cookie value is defined.